# linkage errors multiply defined

Tags: linker

I get 2 types of linking erros.

One is about "multiply defined symbols"

The other is about something like "symbol stats has different sizes in"

I cannot understand how to solve them.
Could you please help me ?

```
[elxr] (error) symbol isalnum multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol isalpha multiply defined in:    
[elxr] (error) symbol isblank multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol iscntrl multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol isdigit multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol isgraph multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol islower multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol isprint multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol ispunct multiply defined in:    
[elxr] (error) symbol isspace multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol isupper multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol isxdigit multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol tolower multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol toupper multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol isascii multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol toascii multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol isalnum multiply defined in:    
[elxr] (error) symbol isalpha multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol isblank multiply defined in:    
[elxr] (error) symbol iscntrl multiply defined in:    
[elxr] (error) symbol isdigit multiply defined in:    
[elxr] (error) symbol isgraph multiply defined in:    
[elxr] (error) symbol islower multiply defined in:    
[elxr] (error) symbol isprint multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol ispunct multiply defined in:    
[elxr] (error) symbol isspace multiply defined in:    
[elxr] (error) symbol isupper multiply defined in:    
[elxr] (error) symbol isxdigit multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol tolower multiply defined in:    
[elxr] (error) symbol toupper multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol isascii multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol toascii multiply defined in:

objs\kernel\syslog.o
objs\kernel\cfdp_server.o

[elxr] (error) symbol isalnum multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol isalpha multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol isblank multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol iscntrl multiply defined in: 
[elxr] (error) symbol isdigit multiply defined in:

objs\kernel\syslog.o
objs\kernel\syslog_server.o

[elxr] (error) symbol isgraph multiply defined in:        
[elxr] (error) symbol islower multiply defined in:    
[elxr] (error) symbol isprint multiply defined in:    
[elxr] (error) symbol ispunct multiply defined in:    
[elxr] (error) symbol isspace multiply defined in:    
[elxr] (error) symbol isupper multiply defined in:    
[elxr] (error) symbol isxdigit multiply defined in:    
[elxr] (error) symbol tolower multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol toupper multiply defined in:    
[elxr] (error) symbol isascii multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol toascii multiply defined in:

objs\kernel\syslog.o
objs\kernel\syslog_server.o

[elxr] (warning) symbol stats has different sizes in:

objs\kernel\syslog.o
..\GHS\int507\bilge8260\libitcpip.a(v3main.o)

[elxr] (error) symbol isalnum multiply defined in:    
[elxr] (error) symbol isalpha multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol isblank multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol iscntrl multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol isdigit multiply defined in:    
[elxr] (error) symbol isgraph multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol islower multiply defined in:    
[elxr] (error) symbol isprint multiply defined in:    
[elxr] (error) symbol ispunct multiply defined in:    
[elxr] (error) symbol isspace multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol isupper multiply defined in:    
[elxr] (error) symbol isxdigit multiply defined in:    
[elxr] (error) symbol tolower multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol toupper multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol isascii multiply defined in:
[elxr] (error) symbol toascii multiply defined in:


objs\kernel\syslog.o
lib\pus\libpus.a(os_abstract.o)

[elxr] (warning) symbol stats has different sizes in:

..\GHS\int507\myBSP\libitcpip.a(v3main.o)
lib\pus\libpus.a(os_abstract.o)

[elxr] (warning) symbol stats has different sizes in:

..\GHS\int507\myBSP\libitcpip.a(v3main.o)
lib\pus\libpus.a(pus.o)
[elxr] (error) errors during processing
Error: build failed
Build failed (Fri Oct 14 17:27:31 2011)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing your using two different header files where the following symbols are defined. 
The clash regarding symbol stats has different sizes in, must also be due to the same issue.

Eg. If module 1 is cplusplus based and has iostream.h included and module 2 is C based and has stdio.h included, and if i combine module 1 and module 2 to create a single module, issues such as __STDOUT,  __STDIN,   __STDERR is multiply defined will show up.  I presume the issue reported is similar.